# last character not rotating correctly

Tags: java, string, encryption, caesar-cipher

I've written a code for Caesar cipher where 1st input is length of string without any spaces, 2nd input is string to be rotated & 3rd is key by which to rotate. My code is working except the last character of string. For that some strange character is coming instead of an alphabet. Please help!!!..I'm at my wits end..just can't figure out! Below is the code:-

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int length,rotate,i,x;
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s;
    length=scan.nextInt();
    s=scan.next();
    rotate=scan.nextInt();
    char c[]=s.toCharArray();
    for(i=0;i<length;i++) {
    x=c[i];
    if(((x>65)||(x==65))&&((x==90)||(x<90))) {
    x=x+rotate;
    if(x>90)
    x=x-90;
    }
    else if(((x>97)||(x==97))&&((x==122)||(x<122))) {
    x=x+rotate;
    if(x>122)
    x=x-122;
    }
    c[i]=(char)x;
    }
    System.out.println();
    for(i=0;i<length;i++) 
    System.out.print(c[i]);
    }
    }
```

input is:-

```
    11
    middle-Outz
    2
```

output should be:-

```
    okffng-Qwvb
```

but instead my output is coming as:-

```
    okffng-Qwv
```

please help!!! please...someone tell whats the mistake in my code!

Comment: please take the time to format your code properly prior to posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't currently have any logic to handle the case where a letter wraps around to the start of the alphabet if the rotation shift exceed a certain threahhold.  Your logic should be to add to the base value (i.e. first letter) the remainder of the initial shift plus the rotation amount divided by the size of the alphabet.  Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int length, rotate, i, x;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s;
    // don't input the length of the array, let it tell you what its length is
    //length = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    s = scan.nextLine();
    // make sure you really enter a pure integer here, to avoid a crash
    rotate = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    char c[] = s.toCharArray();
    for (i=0; i < c.length; i++) {
        x = c[i];
        int base;
        if (x >= 65 && x <= 90) {
            base = 65;
        }
        else if (x >= 97 && x <= 122) {
            base = 97;
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
        int diff = x - base;
        x = base + (rotate + diff) % 26;
        c[i] = (char)x;
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (i=0; i < c.length; i++) 
        System.out.print(c[i]);
}
```

Note that I chose to not modify a character which is not either a lowercase or uppercase English letter.  In case of other characters, they would not be rotated.

Follow the link below for a demo which shows that the input `middle-Outz` is correctly being transformed to `okffng-Qwvb`.

## Rextester

**Update:**

As you correctly pointed out, you also had some problems with your `Scanner` logic.  A safe pattern to use it to always read everything in a string line, and then parse/format the input as appropriate.  The input mismatch exception you were getting was probably due to incorrect use of the scanner.

Comment: This code is perfect but I have a few doubts..would be grateful if they were cleared..

Comment: @Priya Let me know your questions and I can try to clear them.

Comment: (1) the code that I first posted in question was giving me input mismatch exception in netbeans...can you please tell why?                                     
(2)What is happening to base integer in your written code if its not an alphabet?                                                                                                      (3) The  .length()  function is working without the brackets ().....so does this work everywhere or only in for loops () isnt required? Is it valid for other Java functions like toCharArray, toUpperCase etc?

Comment: 1) caused by entering the wrong input into your `Scanner`, 2) If not a lowercase or uppercase letter, it doesn't get shifted, 3) No, length is not working with parentheses, because in your code you defined a _variable_ called `length`, this is why it "works."

Comment: but I was entering the same input for it as I'm for the new code...So I don't get why it was showing Input Mismatch Exception in netbeans though else where it was working.

Comment: See [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-util-inputmismatchexception-how-to-solve-inputmismatchexception/).  You found another problem with your code that I missed.  Making an update now.

Comment: See [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-util-inputmismatchexception-how-to-solve-inputmismatchexception/).  You found another problem with your code that I missed.  Making an update now.